# email sending using php dont succeed

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

Trying to send send email using php, uploaded to my server the files:timeoutfix.diff,smtp.inc.php,phpmailer.inc.php and still the mail is not sent. 
anyone can help me?

HTML form:

```
            <form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />

            <label for="Company">Company:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Company" id="Company" />

            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />

            <label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
            <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
        </form>
```

php code:

```
<?php
$Subject = "Email from test website";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Company = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Company'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 
// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Company: ";
$Body .= $Company;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

require("phpmailer.inc.php");
$mail = new phpmailer;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->From = "test@test.com";
$mail->FromName = " Gartner Israel";
$mail->Host = "62.219.91.15";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->AddAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
$mail->IsHTML(true);    // set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = "Email from test website";
$mail->Body = $Body;

if ($mail->Send();){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
}


?>
```

Comment: If you're using `stripslashes` then you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on, which it should not be.

Comment: check the logs in your server and check waht are the erros are being created there

Comment: I get no errors in the log

Comment: @tadman, can you explain your comment for a php newbie?

Comment: @gal Unless you have the magic quotes feature of PHP turned on, `stripslashes` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is related to the "from" field - presumably you do not own test.com?  Try removing this, and testing the send with your default php send server.  If that works, then you can look into using a more useful address there.

Comment: i wrote there the right information... i changed it to test because i published it here

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **semicolon**, I see an error there in the check condition

```
if ($mail->Send();)
```

Comment: First try this simple script:
`if(mail('your@emailaddress.com', 'Test Subject', "Test message"))
echo "sent";
else echo "not sent";`
If it doesn;t work, check your error logs.